# Random Number Generator (Command Line)

Tags: swift, command-line

When the user enters a number they have to guess the random number. These are the errors I am getting for this line of code which is in the code twice.

"Value of type "String has no number "stringByReplacingOccruencesOfString"

```
input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withSring:"",
```

Here is the full code

```
import Foundation

var randomNumber = 1
var userGuess:Int? = 1
var continueGuessing = true
var keepPlaying = true
var input = ""

while (keepPlaying) {
randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101)) 
// gets a random number between 0-   1000

print("The random number to guess is:\(randomNumber)");
while (continueGuessing) {
    print ("Print a number between 0 and 100")
    input = NSString(data: FileHandle.standardInput.availableData,
    encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String // gets keyboard input
    input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withSring:"",
    options: NSString.CompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    userGuess = Int(input)
    if (userGuess == randomNumber){
        continueGuessing = false
        print("Correct Number!");
    }
    else if (userGuess! > randomNumber){
        print("Your guess is too high");
    }
    else{
        print("Your guess is too low");

    }
}
print ("Play Again? Y or N");
input = NSString(data: FileHandle.standardInput.availableData,
encoding:String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String
input = input.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "",
options: NSString.CompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

if(input == "N" || input == "n"){
    keepPlaying = false
}
continueGuessing = true

}
```

Comment: `withSring` is a typo? – Not also that the method names changed a lot in Swift  3. (But "Convert to Current Swift Syntax" should help)

Comment: Whichever Swift version this is, assuming you're using Xcode, you can solve your problem by deleting the method call, typing `input.replacing` and seeing what auto-complete offers you.

Comment: Or browse the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string) ...

Comment: converting just added more errors

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed code

```
import Foundation

var randomNumber = 1
var userGuess:Int? = 1
var continueGuessing = true
var keepPlaying = true
var input = ""

while (keepPlaying) {
randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(101))
// gets a random number between 0-   1000

print("The random number to guess is:\(randomNumber)");
while (continueGuessing) {
    print ("Print a number between 0 and 100")
    if let input = readLine() {
        if let userGuess = Int(input) {
            if (userGuess == randomNumber){
                continueGuessing = false
                print("Correct Number!");
            }
            else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
                print("Your guess is too high");
            }
            else{
                print("Your guess is too low");

            }

        } else {
            print("Bad input data");
        }
    }
}
print ("Play Again? Y or N");
input = readLine()!
if(input == "N" || input == "n"){
    keepPlaying = false
}
continueGuessing = true

}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution of your question?